# Storing an Excel Add-In in an existing workbook

Tags: c#, excel, deployment, excel-addins

I'm currently developing an Excel Add-In using the Excel-DNA library. Sadly I need to serialize the Add-In somehow into the workbook so if the workbook is opened, the Add-In's code may be executed.

Before, I worked with VBA and Excel macros which've been run greatly, I could serialize the macro and upload the workbook. A software put data into it and delivered the edited workbook and I just had to open the workbook for the macro to execute.

I tried that with an Add-In (e.g. loading the Add-In and saving the workbook) but that didn't work, the Add-In seems to be not saved at all. Is there any other chance in serializing the Add-In into a workbook so people who just got the workbook can execute the Add-In's code?

Comment: I don't think you can do it that way. The benefit of an add-in is that it separates code from data, but that comes at a cost of harder deployment. Can you put code in the workbook that installs the addin? You'd still require separate files, but might be a better user experience.

Comment: @DickKusleika What do you mean by _put code in the workbook that installs the addin_? Is that even possible? The software is storing the workbook somehow, at least the macros have been stored.

Comment: I wrote that poorly, let me try again. You have two files, an add-in and a workbook that the add-in uses or interacts with in some way. Can you use the Workbook_Open event procedure to write registry entries that effectively installs the add-in, which then could do its thing on the workbook? I would think your workbook is not macro enabled now because all the code is in the addin. So you'd have to macro enable it so it contain this small bit of code that installs the addin.

Comment: Brilliant idea, never thought of this one! According to [this](http://excelribbon.tips.net/T011788_Automatically_Loading_Add-ins.html) article this should be possible to install. Is there a chance that I can set the path to the Add-In so I wouldn't need to configure it before? Oh and please, write that as detailed answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include code in the Excel workbook that will install the add-in if it isn't already. You could also have it uninstall the add-in on close if you only want the add-in installed while the workbook is open.

Check out JKP's Name Manager, specifically the code in the Setup Name Manager file.

http://www.jkp-ads.com/OfficeMarketPlaceNM-EN.asp

It finds the add-in, which is assumed to be in the same path and as the Setup file, and copies it to the UserLibrary, which is the default path for add-ins. Then it sets the Addin.Installed property to True.

JKP's addin is and native Excel add-in, not an Excel DNA one, so there may be some differences (and I don't know what they are). But you may have to deal with Application.COMAddins rather than Application.Addins.

Comment: To load an Excel-DNA add-in you'd just call Application.RegisterXLL to load it. Note that any functions in the add-in are global to Excel, and not restricted to the particular workbook.

Comment: @Govert Thanks but I needed some sort of a bootstrapper that is run once the document has opened. This is why I used VBA to install the Excel-DNA Add-In.

Comment: @Mostey I just meant that in your VBA you can call Application.RegisterXLL, which is easier than fiddling with Application.AddIns.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand Add-Ins, they sit separately in a way they can't be bound together with a workbook. The way I have understood them (and used them up to this point) is, for lack of a better term, a weird 'mini-program' that sits loaded inside Excel itself, not inside your workbook - you install it, it has access to more PC resources, Add-Ins even land in the list of programs for Windows, unlike a VBA macro.

Add-Ins solve a lot of problems, but do create a new one in the process. Even if you built a process that reached out on launch for the addin to install, I think it would still require a restart of Excel to be accessible from within the application, which would be frustrating. Add-In deployment is still fairly clunky, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Where I work we have a deployment process to deliver a Start Menu entry that will open excel and the correct version of the xll.

I have never heard of people embedding the addin in the workbook. But you can do the opposite, your addin can be coupled with a XLA or you can create an Addin menu with entries for the user to open a specific version of the workbook. This tie the workbook to a specific version of the addin rather than the opposite like you asked but it may be useful for your purposes. Uou could use a network drive for a basic implementation.

This would achieve kind of the same result by inverting your logic. However this is a costly solution in terms of manpower to create this infrastructure.

Comment: Yep, a network drive will fit most in my situation. My co-workers should immediately feel comfortable when using the add-in for the first name. I thought about adding a small ribbon menu with 2 buttons for controlling the add-in. Do you know how costly the rollout may be? Meaning, do I just need to add the nas-path to the add-in and everything will just work? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What you could do, is have a .xla that will read a config file somewhere in a fixed location. This .xla will contain the list of xll to load and load them. Then you need to make a VBA script that will read a network drive and create a menu entry for folder and file (i.e. reproduce the directory structure in a menu). It takes some time but it shouldn't be too hard.